# Mailtrain-AWS SES: The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: email, amazon-ses, smtp-auth

I set up mailtrain to send emails using AWS SES.

However, the emails bounce with the following reason: " The security token included in the request is invalid."

[image: Image 3]

Additionally, emails get sent successfully sometimes, but majority of time I get the error.